# How to upload/attach file to JIRA using RestAssured

Tags: rest-assured

I'm trying to attach/Upload in jira through Restassured API testing.

I'm using POST method to upload a file.

But jira rest doc. says use CURL to attach file, If so how to write jav code for that in restassured

**Curl command** :

```
curl -D- -u admin:admin -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@myfile.txt" myhost/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-123/attachments
```

**Code :**

```
given(). multiPart("file2", new File("/home/xyz/assume.log")). expect(). body("fileUploadResult", is("OK")). when(). post("localhost:8181/rest/api/2/issue/AT-2/attachments");
```

Comment: Have you tried something with rest assured already ? And also let us know the CURL command according to the JIRA rest doc

Comment: Yes, I already tried with post method, but not working.

Comment: CURL command: curl -D- -u admin:admin -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@myfile.txt" http://myhost/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-123/attachments

Comment: Here is my Code:                                                                                      
         given().
         multiPart("file2", new File("/home/xyz/assume.log")).
         expect().
         body("fileUploadResult", is("OK")).
         when().
         post("http://localhost:8181/rest/api/2/issue/AT-2/attachments");

Comment: -U denotes that you have used authentication | -H for headers | but I do not see both being used in the code that you have pasted

Comment: Yes need authentication headers to add, thanks @WilfredClement

Answer (score 3):

Yes perfect need to add authentication and header
Here is my working code:

```
given()
.auth()
.preemptive()
.basic("Jirausername", "Jirapassword")
.header("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck")
.multiPart(new File("/home/users/cat.log"))
.when().post("http://localhost:8181/rest/api/2/issue/STS-223/attachments");
```